# No applications in Dash

Tags: unity-dash

I think that, due to latest Trusty s/w updates, none of my applications (including standard Trusty installed ones) are available from the Dash! Or have I done something to cause this? The Applications category is enabled on Categories & Sources.
PS this is only happening on my desktop i.e. not on my laptop. Both computers had clean installs of Trusty.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was reported in Ubuntu Forums in 2011. The problem appears to be a corrupted .cache. I removed $HOME/.cache and after a log out/log in, dash went back to its normal behaviour.